# UIMA Ruta: Creating new annotations by combining existing annotation's features in plain Java

Tags: java, annotations, uima, ruta

I'm trying to convert the following logic into a UIMA Ruta Rule:

`Sentence {->NewAnnotation}` *IF* `Sentence.part1` *contains* `Constituent.label="VB"` *AND* `Sentence.part2` *contains* `Constituent.label="VBZ"`

**In other words, I need to create a new annotation out of the entire Sentence and whose feature *part1*(and *part2*) contains combinations/a sequence of specific posTags (Constituent.label).**

At first, an intuitive answer for me was to use the `CONTAINS` condition along with a `STRINGLIST`(and config parameters) in the following manner:

```
STRINGLIST posList; //assuming it is declared
Sentence{-> NewAnnotation} <-{Sentence.part1{CONTAINS(posList, Constituent.label)};};
```

But it doesn't produce any annotations(yet it doesn't fail).

Then I considered the `GETFEATURE` action by storing the `Sentence` feature(`Sentence.part1`) in a string variable and using it separately(in the main rule). However, since `GETFEATURE` saves the feature in a `STRING` format so I cannot use it to produce annotations (since I need `ANNOTATION` type). Same happens with `MATCHEDTEXT` action.

I understand the rule a want to build is quite complex but I believe Ruta is the most suitable option for such tasks. So, **can you please suggest me any ideas of how to deal with my problem?**

Comment: In your rule, Constituent is most likely resolved against a different annotation, which causes the rule to fail. Did you try to add another inlined rule as consition like: `Sentence{-> NewAnnotation} <-{Sentence.part1<-{Constituent.label="VB";};};` The challenge would then be to specify the `AND` for the two sentence parts. You could probably solve this with a conjunct rule using `%` or with a boolean variable in a BLOCK/FOREACH.

Comment: Yes, I tried this but it throws an exception: `"=": expected SEMI, but found ASSIGN_EQUAL`. I think it only accepts annotations without features. So, here the solution would be to first prepare annotations out of `Constituent.label="VB/VBZ/VBP..."` even if this is quite naive. What do you think?

Comment: Ah sorry, should of course read: `Sentence{-> NewAnnotation} <-{Sentence.part1<-{Constituent.label=="VB";};};` with == (comparison) instead of = (assignment, not allowed here). I will create a tested set of rules when I find the time.

Comment: Yes you can prepare special annotations, but that should not be necessary.

Comment: Oh sure, I missed that somehow. However, it still doesn't produce any annotations even though no exceptions are thrown. If you say the rule should be valid in Ruta, then I suspect the problem is in `Constituent.label=="VB"`;so, I will try to replace that with a special annotation(no features).

Comment: I just realized where the problem is: in my case the `Sentence` is a _jcas_ but  the `Sentence.part1` is a _string_. Consequently, Ruta fails to find posTags in strings; so I have to find a way to convert the features to _jcas_ and only then to apply the rule. The suggested rule works fine, I tested it on a _jcas_.

Comment: Do you want to add an answer to your question (assuming your problem is solved)?

Comment: @PeterKluegl, a quick related question, if I may:

I was under the impression that negating a `CONTAINS` condition should be performed in the following way:

`... <-{Sentence.part1{-CONTAINS(posList, Constituent.label)};};`

But for some strange reason it doesn't work at all. Have you ever experienced anything like this? (or I am doing something wrong?)

Comment: Hard to say. If `CONTAINS` works correctly, then I would assume that `Constituent` resolves to the wrong annoation, the first one, and the correct label would be in a later annoation? Is there more than one Constituent in a sentence part?

Comment: Yes, the `CONTAINS` works just fine. `Constituent.label` is a string as well as the `posList` elements. Indeed, there are more than one `Constituent` annotations for the `part1` but I suspected the rule to take each one of them and to compare against the `posList` (if it's there or not). Isn't this so? (since the execution of `CONTAINS` works in this way)

Comment: `Constituent.label` is interpreted as a string expression (type + feature). The value of the string is calculated by using the feature of an annotation. The annotation is only given by the type, so simply the first annotation of that type within the matching context is utilized. This has nothing to do with the COTAINS yet. This is why you probably need the stacked inlined rules.

Comment: I finally tried to reproduce the rule. There seems to be a problem with the conjunct rules.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right, but I tested sequentially each feature of the type `CONSTITUENT` for a possible match and nothing works. I doubt it's a matter of the conjunct rules since I tried the same without any other conjunct rules and still no luck. Regarding the usage of stacked inlined rules: Is there any other method to stack them without using conjunction?

Comment: Yes, right now, you can specify the conjunctuion with boolean variables: [uima user mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/uima-user/201702.mbox/%3Ca43e982c-38a2-d82d-f6f5-682b612c8d87%40averbis.com%3E)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PeterKluegl already stated, the solution to the original question would be:

```
Sentence{-> NewAnnotation} <-{Sentence.part1<-{Constituent.label=="VB";} %
                              Sentence.part2<-{Constituent.label=="VB";};};
```

Mind that this rule would work only if the `Sentence` features (i.e `part1`) are annotations and not strings as it is in my case.

So, for potential interested people, I post also the solution approached in my case:

- Store `Sentence` features in separate annotations but keeping the link between the `Sentence.part1` and its parent `Sentence` (this is possible in UIMA via parent pointers).
- Apply the following rule:

  ```
  String rutaRule = "STRING id;"
          + "STRING part1Id;"
          + "STRING part2Id;"
          + "Sentence{->GETFEATURE(\"matchId\", id)};"
          + "part1{->GETFEATURE(\"parent\", part1Id)};"
          + "part2{->GETFEATURE(\"parent\", part2Id)};"
          + "Sentence{AND(IF(id == part1Id), IF(id == part2Id))-> NewAnnotation} <-"
          + "{part1<-{Constituent.label == \"VBD\";} % "
          + "part2<-{Constituent.label == \"MD\" # Constituent.label == \"VBN\";};};";

  Ruta.apply(cas,rutaRule);
  ```

Hope this can be of any help.